# Why do i have an error when trying to start apache drill in embedded mode?

Tags: java, windows-10, apache-drill

win10, 64bit, no hadoop variable in local(or is tried both). Need drill to gain access to db while testing api. JAVA_HOME is set correctly as also PATH contains directory for jdc bin folder.When i try to start drill-embedded.bat i got the followng error message(not full cause stack doesn't allow to paste bigger piece of code):

```
Error: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION ERROR: Failure while attempting to load instance of the class of type org.apache.drill.exec.store.StoragePluginRegistry requested at path drill.exec.storage.registry.


[Error Id: 3a07daa6-a6bc-4a8e-996a-67bc3aa3a9f4 ] (state=,code=0)
java.sql.SQLException: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION ERROR: Failure while attempting to load instance of the class of type org.apache.drill.exec.store.StoragePluginRegistry requested at path drill.exec.storage.registry.


[Error Id: 3a07daa6-a6bc-4a8e-996a-67bc3aa3a9f4 ]
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:137)
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:67)
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:67)
        at org.apache.calcite.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:138)
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:75)
        at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:135)
        at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:192)
        at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1364)
        at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1244)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:38)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:730)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:410)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:515)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:267)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:206)
Caused by: org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserException: UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION ERROR: Failure while attempting to load instance of the class of type org.apache.drill.exec.store.StoragePluginRegistry requested at path drill.exec.storage.registry.
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange error.  What version of Drill are you using?

Does it make a difference if you use this command:

```
sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"
```

What it looks like is happening is that the storage plugin registry is somehow corrupted. If storage plugin files are manually edited, or otherwise altered outside of Drill, this can happen.

Comment: How can i check it? sqllinebat returns the same error.

Comment: Are you using a clean installation of Drill?  In my experience, if you simply download Drill from drill.apache.org and unzip it, it will run without issues assuming you have Java correctly installed.  Did you modify your configuration files at all?

Comment: i just dl and uziped it. I didn't modify config file.